# Есть ли какое-то ограничение на количество элементов в атрибуте script html?

Tags: html

Wordpress сайт. Из php достаю json данные (с базы) и вставляю их на страницу, как:

```
$data = "window.testObject = {//Тут данные.};"
return <script>$data</script>
```

Иногда получаю белый экран. После нескольких обновлений страницы.
Включал debug в wordpress. Там только Deprecated и Notice. Ничего критичного.

JSON паршу на JS. Но в случае с белым экраном страница вообще не приходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Локализировал проблему до этой части. Но упорно не могу понять причину. Причем проявляется только на одном сайте, из нескольких... К сожалению, более подробной информации предоставить не могу, так как сам не понимаю, что тут может идти не так.

Может ли быть какое-то ограничение на количество данных в атрибуте script?

Ситуация еще более веселая тем, что ошибка вылетает только когда залогинен как админ в wordpress. Когда как гость, все хорошо. Хотя данные отдаю одинаковые. Там ни единой проверки на юзеров, в принципе, нет.

### Update:

Судя по всему, ограничение на размер страницы wordpress.

Продюссирую так:

```
$b = str_repeat('a', 2e6);
echo $b;
```

А так работает:

```
$b = str_repeat('a', 2e1);
echo $b;
```

Может быть какой-то плагин на это влияет?

Comment: Что там по дебагу, что в логах? Ну и правильнее было бы получить этот JSON посредством аякс запроса на сервер.

Comment: @Simon добавил. Там deprecated и php notice. Весь сайт с подобными ошибками. Ничего, чтобы отвечало за эту часть кода в логах не вижу. Ajax не подойдет. Клиент хотел prefetch. Данные должны прилетать вместе с страницей.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `wp_localize_script`, если считаете, что ошибка именно в этой части